# Error accessing Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

**Since today my app throws this error:**

Thanks for helping!

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporärer Fehler bei der Namensauflösung in /var/www/modules/facebook/classes/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 3663

Warning: fopen(http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&session_key=&api_key=6803c8d8b2e3a1fdh4sd154g755b757e&v=1.0) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporärer Fehler bei der Namensauflösung in /var/www/modules/facebook/classes/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 3663
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a programming issue, nor does it have anything to do with FQL.

It appears that your DNS server is failing, or is otherwise unavailable:

```
getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

(translated from German above)

Also, you just published your API key publicly. I assume that's not a good idea.